# Excel Using AND and OR together on the IF function

Tags: excel-formula

I have a problem that I cant figure out how to solve. currently I am solving this in excel but eventually be using sql.

We have a survey which is meant to run when the billed amount reaches ;

•first trigger $50k, then $150, then $250.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqFjE.png)

'last run' is when the survey last ran and 'Current Value' is the current billed amount.

So for row 1 , the survey last ran when billed amount was 55000 and now it is 160000 which is greater than the threshold 150K so survey should run hence it should return 'true'.

Row 2 : is also true because current value is greater than 'last run and also 'is >= 150K
Row 3:  is also true because it has passed the threshold of 150K
Row 4 : should return false because between last ran and current value there isn't any threshold passed.

If 
CurrentValue >= Last Run 
And Current Value >= 50K or 150K or 250K

then 'True' Else false

We are going to drive the survey Initiation from the true or false returned from this.

The data is only sample data , values for current and last run can change but the trigger amounts will remain the same.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question this way:

> You want to calculate which trigger the *last Run*  value was checked against, and which trigger the *Current Value* is checked against, and if they are different and the *Current Value*  is greater than *last Run* then we need to run the survey again (return `TRUE`), otherwise we don't (return `FALSE`).

If the above understanding is incorrect, please let me know.

To calculate this I would simply build one IF-statement expression that determines which trigger that *last Run* used, and the same for *Current Value*, and compare them.

Here are the two formulas:

- `=IF(A2>=250000;3;IF(A2>=150000;2;IF(A2>=50000;1;0)))`
- `=IF(B2>=250000;3;IF(B2>=150000;2;IF(B2>=50000;1;0)))`

Then we need to put it all together, so here's the final formula:

```
=AND(
    IF(A2>=250000;3;IF(A2>=150000;2;IF(A2>=50000;1;0)))
    <>IF(B2>=250000;3;IF(B2>=150000;2;IF(B2>=50000;1;0)))
    ;B2>A2)
```

*(remove linebreaks and put it all together on one long line)*